# Creating custom data annotation validation in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

For instance, I have an Employee view model. When creating an employee, I want to validate the username to make sure it doesn't exist.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ValidateDuplicate(ErrorMessage = "That username already exists")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And then have my ValidateDuplicate function somewhere with the code to check for a duplicate.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [remote validation.](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/04/ASPNETMVC3RemoteValidationTutorial.aspx) The example even matches your case.

Basically, add the remote attribute to your viewmodel property that points to a controller action

```
[Remote("IsUserExists", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Can't add what already exists!")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
[DisplayName("Username")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

which does your work

```
public ActionResult IsUserExists(string userName) 
{
 if (!UserService.UserNameExists(userName) || (CurrentUser.UserName == userName))
 {
      return "Ok.";
 }
}
```

Comment: David Hayden migrated his blog to elsewhere and appears he did not port back his old blog posts (or couldn't). That being said, here's a link directly to Microsoft's documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You'll need to [write your own validation attribute](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/03/11/custom-validation-attributes/).

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own custom validation as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). I've modified the code to add validation in the model as I prefer rails active record's validation style in the model.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{

    [CustomValidation(typeof(EmployeeViewModel), "ValidateDuplicate")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public static ValidationResult ValidateDuplicate(string username)
    {
      bool isValid;

      using(var db = new YourContextName) {
        if(db.EmployeeViewModel.Where(e => e.Username.Equals(username)).Count() > 0)
       {
          isValid = false;
       } else {
          isValid = true;
       }
      }

      if (isValid)
      {
        return ValidationResult.Success;
      }
      else
      {
        return new ValidationResult("Username already exists");
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by extending the Attribute class calling it ValidateDuplicate.  I'd avoid doing it this way because its just another place where you potentially have to make a call to a database.