# Check against DataBase just using DataAnnotations and ValidationMethods

Tags: entity-framework, validation, data-annotations, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

To make my need easier to explain I will use a case that everybody knows.

Remember when you are registering a new Hotmail account, when entering the new Microsoft Account and you **leave the field**, this value is validated against the database to check if it's available.

How do I do that using just DataAnnotations and Validation Methods on the DomainService metadata?

I'm using an ADO NET Entity Model autogenerated from a SQL Express Database, RIA Services, Data Annotations, Validation Methods, and Silverlight 5.

I just checked Jeff Handley's blog on the subject, and he introduces a solution that involves creating a service that makes the Data available from the validation method on the server. The problem is that this solution doesn't work well on my case, he uses a two tables entity model, and makes some tricks that only work with that simple case and not on mine.

Have somebody worked out this problem succesfully?

I could create a stored procedure and invoke it just before submitting changes in the silverlight app or I could make the extra validation in the OnSave method of my ViewModel, but it means that I'm completing the validation process from the client, and I'd like to do it entirely from the server to avoid repeating code.

Besides, I would like to make the validation before pressing "Save".

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how its done: [Creating custom data annotation validation in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526944/creating-custom-data-annotation-validation-in-mvc-3).

Briefly they check user name availability against the database during registration

**Edit**

I think here is better link (not Q-A, but actual article on How-To):

[How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The answer there is vague.

One of them talks about a UserService, what if I want to check Inventory or something else?

The other guy talks about "YourContext", in the server side I don't have a context, so, I needmore help here, this guy doesn't say how to get a context there...

Comment: It's more like it. I think it is an answer.

Thank you