# Create an Attribute for a Text Field that Verifies its Uniqueness

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC, I have a view that POSTs a ViewModel with the information in the form. How can I make an attribute that polls the database and checks if the entered text exists? I'm using Entity Framework for the database connection, so I'm just wondering if it's possible to create an attribute that would run a check somehow.

Comment: This sounds like a good requirement for AJAX.  Make an async call to do the leg work.  That'd be the best UX in my opinion.

Comment: Adding on to the AJAX comment, take a look at this related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526944/creating-custom-data-annotation-validation-in-mvc-3

Comment: I've never seen that before, it looks like it'd solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that `RemoteAttribute` is for performing a client side call. You still need check for uniqueness in the POST method